# Custom function returns the same value for all rows in dplyr's mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
                                                 Name
1                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
2 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)
3                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
4        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
5                            Allen, Mr. William Henry
```

The data can be loaded like:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", "Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)", 
"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina", "Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)", 
"Allen, Mr. William Henry")), .Names = "Name", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My expected output is:

```
                                                 Name    Title
1                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris       Mr
2 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)      Mrs
3                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina      Mrs
4        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)      Mrs
5                            Allen, Mr. William Henry       Mr
```

The problem is that below code would set all `Title`s to just `"Mr"`. I'm using a custom function with dplyr's `mutate`.

```
library('stringr')
library('dplyr')

extractTitle <- function(name) {
  str_match(name, '(\\b[a-zA-z]+)\\.')[2]
}

data <- data %>% 
          mutate(Title = extractTitle(Name))
```

The weird thing is that if I change extractTitle to return the argument as is, it works as expected. For example:

```
extractTitle <- function(name) {
  name
}

data <- data %>% 
          mutate(Title = extractTitle(Name))
```

The above code will return:

```
                                                 Name    Title
1                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
2 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)
3                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina
4        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)
5                            Allen, Mr. William Henry   Allen, Mr. William Henry
```

This is my expected behavior which is different from the behavior of the code I'm having trouble with.

Is there something I'm missing here or is this a bug?

P.S. - I'm using dplyr version 0.5.0

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? It is mostly better to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I just added the input and expected output as you suggested. This is my first time posting a question for R here in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)    
data %>%
      mutate(title = str_extract(string = Name, pattern = "(Mr|Miss|Mrs)\\.")) %>%
      select(Name, title)
```

which returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
                                                 Name title
                                                <chr> <chr>
1                             Braund, Mr. Owen Harris   Mr.
2 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)  Mrs.
3                              Heikkinen, Miss. Laina Miss.
4        Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  Mrs.
5                            Allen, Mr. William Henry   Mr.
6                                    Moran, Mr. James   Mr.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using `str_exact` fixes it! Looks like the problem was with using the `str_match` function. Any idea why?